# How to listen when data is pushed

Tags: java, atmosphere, portaljs

I'm using the `portal` javascript library to interact with my Java sockets.  I can't seem to determine how to get a request mapped to a method on the below resource.  A socket is being established correctly with `@Path("workstation/approval/{uuid}")` and then JSON data is being passed through the connection.  But on the Java side, **how do I map that data push to a method so I can process it?**

```
@Path("workstation/approval/{uuid}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class WorkstationResource {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Context
    private BroadcasterFactory broadcasterFactory;

    @GET
    @Suspend
    public Broadcastable get(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
        return new Broadcastable(getBroadcaster(uuid));
    }

    private Broadcaster getBroadcaster(String uuid) {
        return broadcasterFactory.lookup(JerseyBroadcaster.class, "workstation/approval/"+uuid, true);
    }

    public String onMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString("This is a test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using WebSocket or Comet? In any case, try adding a @Post annotated method and that will work. Come to the Atmosphere [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/atmosphere-framework?pli=1) if you have more questions, or look at the [project sample](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Answer (score 0):

actually its very simple!
just add another parameter to every method
for example, change

```
public Broadcastable get(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid) {
    return new Broadcastable(getBroadcaster(uuid));
}
```

to

```
public Broadcastable get(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid,String postData) {
    return new Broadcastable(getBroadcaster(uuid));
}
```

and you will have the data passed with the connection in postData parameter